# Clarification on UIDocument in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, typename, uidocument

I need a little clarification working with `UIDocument` and I have 3 related questions

-1. In the call:

```
-(id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

from where does the `UIDocument` pickup the `typeName`. Is it from "Document types" in the info.plist of the app if the value is set for that property.

-2. Can one have more than 1 document type for an iOS app, and then if so, how can one determine which type is used when saving and reading documents.

-3. Does `UIDocument` work in the simulator?

Answer (score 2):

So Here is what I have found out probably solving the issues.

-1. in your UIDocument subclass if you want to use a custom type, you need override the call: "-( NSString *)fileType"
returning your custom fileType you want to use. Then this file type is used when UIDocument subclass calls function:

```
-(id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

-2. In this way you can have more than one document type for an application as you can return different fileTypes in "-( NSString *)fileType"

-3. Contrary to what I have read, I seem to have managed to be able to save a UIDocument using the simulator. My previous issue was a poor bug.

I hope this helps

Reza